# SQL in Any vs != Any

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

Students:

```
+------+---------+
| Snum |  Sname  |
+------+---------+
| S1   | Charles |
| S2   | Amy     |
| S3   | John    |
+------+---------+
```

Courses:

```
+-----+------------+
| cid | coursecode |
+-----+------------+
| C1  | CMPT222    |
| C2  | ASC111     |
+-----+------------+
```

Enrollment:

```
+------+-----+
| sid  | cid |
+------+-----+
| S1   | C1  |
| S2   | C2  |
+------+-----+
```

In general, I have three students and two of them are enrolled.
The query is: Find the snums that are not enrolled:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.snum
FROM Student S
WHERE S.snum! = any (SELECT E.snum FROM Enrolled E )
```

This query returns:

```
1
2
3
```

Which is wrong.

My understanding is : for each tuple in the outer query, ANY will check if there is atleast one tuple. if yes then it returns TRUE. If we are using != then it should return 3.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're saying that you have three students that are enrolled, but according to the enrolment table there are only 2 students who are enrolled: S1 and S2. Could you please clarify

Comment: sorry, typo. its two.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.snum
FROM Student S
WHERE S.snum <> any (SELECT E.snum FROM Enrolled E )
```

Basically, if the subquery returns more than one value, then the condition will always be true.  Why?  Well, consider if the returned set is `1` and `2`.  Well,  if you compare a value to one of these, then the condition is always true.  Remember:  `1 <> 2`.  So, if the value matches the first, it does not match the second.

There are simple ways to fix this.  For instance:

```
WHERE NOT (S.snum = any (SELECT E.snum FROM Enrolled E ))
```

Or:

```
WHERE S.snum NOT IN (SELECT E.snum FROM Enrolled E )
```

Actually, I don't like `NOT IN` because it treats `NULL` values differently.  In this case, I prefer `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: in <> any - why its returning three tuples (1,23).

Comment: @zephyr . . . Because the condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Because the predicate you are evaluating is always true, `= any()` at least one equivalence. Not equal or `<> any()` at least one no equivalence. Because of the set returned by your subquery, the last predicate is always true and the former just the `s1` and `s2` values.

Note that, if your subquery would return just one value your result selection would be different.

**Long explanation**

Your subquery return this values: `s1` and `s2`.Then, your rdbms goes row by row evaluating the predicate. Then,

`s1` <> `s1` -> `false`

`s1` <> `s2` -> `true`

Predicate evaluation, `true` because of `any()`.

Next value,

`s2` <> `s1` -> `true`

Predicate evaluation `true`... Third value:

`s3` <> `s1` -> `true`

Note that, `some()` and `any()` are equivalent clauses.

Think of `any()` as an `or` gate. Every time a true is found (input), the output is true.

Comment: @zephyr Then accept the answer so we close the topic. I recommend using `<>` instead of `!=` since `<>` is standard sql and `!=` is non-standard and therefore not a mandatory implementation by rdbms.